# Examples of $\bigcup_{A\in F} A$ and $\bigcup_{r\in \Gamma} A_r$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The following is from *Set theory* by You-Feng Lin, Shwu-Yeng T:

> Let $F$ be an arbitrary family of sets. The union of the sets in $F$, denoted by $\bigcup F$ or $\bigcup_{A \in F} A$, is the set of all elements that are in $A$ for some $A \in F$. That is
>   $$
> \bigcup_{A \in F} A
> = \{ x \in U \mid \text{$x \in A$ for some $A \in F$}\}.
> $$
>   If the family $F$ is indexed by the set $Γ$, the following alternate notation may be used:
>   $$
>  \bigcup_{r \in \Gamma} A_r
> = \{x \in U \mid \text{$x \in A$ for some $r \in \Gamma$}\}
> $$

They can be put simpler in symbols like the following:
$$
 \bigcup_{A\in F} A
 = \{x \in U \mid \exists A \in F : x \in A\}
$$
and
$$
 \bigcup_{r\in Γ} A_r
 = \{ x \in U \mid \exists r \in \Gamma : x \in A \}
$$
if the family $F$ is indexed by the set $Γ$.

But I don't know any examples of $\bigcup_{A \in F} A$ and $\bigcup_{r \in Γ} A_r$. Can you show how they are different with examples?

Comment: Please refrain from using some strange mix of LaTeX and unicode symbols. MathJax is powerful enough for stuff like this.

Comment: @Jendrik Stelzner. I know how to put unicod symbols, but what's LaTex? I tried to use MathJax as possibls as I can, but I didn't know how to apply MathJax for some symbols. As far as I know, I tried to use MathJAx. I'm newbie so please understand that it takes some time to master MathJax.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you find a basic list of what you can do with MathJax, and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) you can find ways to format your text.

Answer (score 0):

I think as stated in the definition, the difference between two notations is whether the family of set is indexed.

For example, if we consider $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of subsets of $\mathbb{N}$. Then the union of all elements of $\mathcal{F}$ can be represented using the first notation. Here we don't assign an index to the family.

Then we know $\mathcal{F}$ contains uncountable many elements, which has same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, hence we can use $\mathbb{R}$ as an index set. That is, we can define a bijection $\phi$ from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\mathcal{F}$, such as $r\to F_r\in \mathcal{F},\forall r\in\mathbb{R}$. With this index set, we can use the second notation to represent the union of all elements of $\mathcal{F}$. Here the index set $\Gamma$ in notation is $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is just about notation. For example, let $\mathcal{F}=\{[0,n): n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $[0,\infty)=\cup_{[0,n)\in \mathcal{F}} [0,n)=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}[0,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the following:

If you write $A\in F$ you assume that the admissible $A$ are defined only implicitly by some condition. An example: $F$ is the family of all closed segments $A\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ of length ${1\over2}$ with one endpoint on the unit sphere $S^2$. Then $\bigcup_{A\in F}A$ is a closed spherical shell with inner radius ${1\over2}$ and outer radius ${3\over2}$.

If you are talking about the family $(A_r)_{r\in\Gamma}$ then you assume that you are given a "production scheme" which for each $r\in\Gamma$ produces an explicit set $A_r$.

In my view one should only talk about a "family" in the second case. In the first case one just has a set of sets.